# Change Static IP without rebooting

Tags: networking, ethernet, static-ip

I have a Pi 3, with the wifi interface connected to one network and the Ethernet interface connected to another network. How can I change the `eth0` static IP I have set from `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and apply those changes without rebooting the Pi? It used to be as simple as changing `/etc/networking/interfaces`, and restarting the `networking` service, but now that it's switched to using `dhcpcd` to configure it, my best attempts, including various combinations of: restarting `dhcpcd`, `networking`, and bringing the `eth0` interface up and down several times, at best will result in me now having both the old and the new static ip, with `ifconfig` showing the old one.

After changing `dhcpcd.conf` and rebooting, it appears normal. But how can I achieve a clean static ip change without rebooting?

Comment: have you tried changing it with:
sudo ifconfig eth0 X.X.X.X netmask 255.255.255.0

Comment: That will change it until the next restart. I'm looking to change it permanently. So it has to be changed in `dhcpcd.conf` then `dhcpcd` must be restarted, and my problem is that restarting it is not applying my new static ip.

Comment: what's the harm in rebooting?

Comment: @tedder42 It will ruin one's uptime record.

Comment: @tedder42 the Pi is logging input from various sensors connected via GPIO. Rebooting would cause it to not log for that period of time.

Comment: I'm now officially intrigued, as I also need to change static IPs occasionally, without rebooting preferably. I'll do some experiments.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd5` should force the system to re-read the config and renew the DHCP lease.

Answer (score 3):

I attached a Python script to apply changes to dhcpcd.conf without rebooting.  The key is to flush the IP addresses for each interface.  It may take a few seconds to apply after the command is executed, but has worked for me.

Python script (note TAB required before "subprocess.call after for loop"):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

import subprocess

NET_DIR='/sys/class/net'

subprocess.call(['sudo','systemctl','daemon-reload'])
subprocess.call(['sudo','systemctl','stop','dhcpcd.service'])

for net_dev in os.listdir(NET_DIR):

    subprocess.call(['sudo','ip','addr','flush','dev',net_dev])

subprocess.call(['sudo','systemctl','start','dhcpcd.service'])
subprocess.call(['sudo','systemctl','restart','networking.service'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me over a remote ssh connection:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.1.71 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo route add default gw 10.0.1.1
```

Where 10.0.1.71 is the Pi's IP address, /24 is the netmask and 10.0.1.1 is the default gateway. You'll still need to update `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` to have the changes survive a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue recently, my old Raspberry Pi became my FreeRadius server and so I set it up with a static IP.

The relevant information from PhillipB's Python script turned out to be running ip addr flush on the interface in question, eth0 in my case. Just restarting dhcpcd.service didn't help.

So here's the simplified solution in my case:

```
sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd.service
sudo ip addr flush dev eth0
sudo systemctl start dhcpcd.service
```